# Draw a simple vertical bar in iphone

Tags: iphone

I wanted to draw a vertical single bar graph. I was trying to do it using DrawRect, but could not able to do so. Can nay one hlep me to knwo if this can be done easily by providing start and end point in view to change the color.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a custom view, it's just a matter of drawing the lines and rectangles that you want. For example:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
    self.transform = t;
    CGFloat baseline = 50;
    CGFloat inset = 40;
    CGFloat barWidth = 20;
    CGFloat barHeight = 80;

    CGRect r = CGRectMake(inset + barWidth, baseline, barWidth, barHeight);
    UIBezierPath *p = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:r];
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    [p fill];
    p = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [p moveToPoint:CGPointMake(inset, baseline)];
    [p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(inset + 3 * barWidth, baseline)];
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    [p stroke];
}
```

produces this:

[image: Sample bar graph]

I've created a UIView subclass with the `-drawRect:` method above and created an instance of that view that's the size of the window. Note that I flipped the coordinate system using a transform -- you don't have to do that, but drawing with the origin at the lower left corner can be easier.

Comment: Great thanks, also if this need to fill up with animation I need to drawrect in loop right?

Comment: @iPhoneDev No, actually you never call `-drawRect:` yourself -- the operating system calls it when it wants the view to draw itself. Animating your view is a bit more (not much, but some) complicated. Start by reading the [*Core Animation Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514), particularly the part about keyframe animations.

Answer (score 0):

try this one
 1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

2 OVGraph.- a library for the graphs

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am looking for simple draw rect method without including any third party lib